# What is the appropriate way of migrating credentials to a new machine?

Tags: ssh, security, ssh-keys

The title probably looks a little too vague, but I feel that if I give more information I might as well put the whole text into the title.

---

Today I have two droplets on DigitalOcean with SSH enabled and without password. I received a new computer last Friday and I want to move my keys so I don't need to regenerate absolutely everything again.

I'm wondering if there's a way to copy the public key of the new machine into the old machine. This way, I can use the old machine to access the servers and copy the `id_rsa` generated on the new machine.

Is this the correct/recommended approach? I think that generating a new key pair for a new machine seems appropriate.

---

Thinking about this, can I just copy the `id_rsa.pub` to the old machine and upload it from there to the servers' authorized keys folder?

I don't have the reputation to do this (yet), but I would also suggest the creation of a tag `worksation-migration` here. :)

Comment: I would use a USB stick.

Comment: The suggestion at the end sounds nicer (just adding the new `id_rsa.pub` to  `authorized_keys`), but as I understand it that is what you started out saying that you wanted to avoid...?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I was just asking if there is an easier way, but I guess it can't be easier than this. Except if I copy the private keys too, which seems not a good practice, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the original position of this question suggests that this key is perceived as near irreplaceable, which is not a good thing operationally.

I would very much suggest the approach of taking this opportunity to generate a new key that replaces the old one (and updating which public key that is authorized to reflect this).
You may also want to consider switching algorithms while you are at it, and add for instance your brand new `id_ed25519.pub` as the new key instead.

I'm thinking that switching keys is a good idea for multiple reasons:

- The old key for sure exists on your old machine and possibly also somewhere else. It has larger risk of being or already having been compromised, compared to a brand new key that would only exist on your new machine.
- Your reluctance to replace the key suggests that you may need to practice.
  Do consider that you may end up in a position where you have to revoke all access for your key ASAP (and probably introducing a replacement key, ie what you need right now); if doing the same thing as a non-urgent action feels this problematic... it's probably good to figure it out.
  And if what you figure out turns out to be a pain, maybe you will find something to improve in your procedures (documentation? automation?).

Comment: So, basically, generate a new key pair and revoke old keys? :P

Comment: @RenatoOliveira That is my suggestion. If you absolutely want to copy the old key, maybe just copy it over ssh between your old and new machines, but I think it seems like a brilliant opportunity to replace the old key.